# VBA Conditional Format .rank value based on a cell - Top10

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I originally needed to select top 5% of the selected items but, it couldn't roundUP the number of highlighted items. For example: If there are 25 items in the list, 5% is 1.25 and Conditional Format is only selecting 1 item. According to my report, it should round it up and select 2 items.

As I couldn't find a way to do this, I decided to manually calculate the number of items which would show how many to be highlighted (in a cell).

1. It would be easier if  there is a way to make the conditional format round up the number of selected items.

such as:
.rank = 5 (but should round it up)
.percent = True

If it is not possible,

2. I would like to highlight the top X values in a column using the conditional formatting.
   The value X (The rank) is calculated in a cell and will change everytime the macro is run.

I've tried the code below but, it doesn't work.

```
Dim i As Integer
    i = Workbooks("a.xlsm").Worksheets("b").Range("A1")

Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
    .Rank = i
    .Percent = False
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0

End With
```

I'm getting the error on ".rank = i" line which makes me think it is not possible to assign a variable there or I might be assigning the cell wrongly.

I also tried ".rank = i.Value" which seems to be wrong as well (Compile error: Invalid qualifier)

I'm a newbie in vba and any help would be appreciated.

ps: using office 365.

Thank you

**Update**: The code above works as long as the "i" value is not zero.
I managed to create a simple If statement to prevent the error.

```vb
'In my report i cannot be below 0
If i > 0 Then
  Insert the code above here
'If there is no data to be highlighted
Else
'Do Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post and example of your input and the expected output?

Comment: If you need a number from a cell containing a number, the usual approach is `rng.Value2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Non-VBA solution can work for you, you can use this. I made a fake dataset, just a list of 25 values (numbers 1 to 25). You want to highlight 5% higher values. 5% of 25 = 1,25, but rounded up it's 2. So you want to highlight any cell which value is one of those top 2 values in this case.

I got this:

[image]

As you can see, values 25 and 24 are highlighted. The Conditional Formatting Rule (CFR) I'm using is based on this formula:

```
=RANK(A1;$A$1:$A$25;0)<=ROUNDUP(COUNTA($A$1:$A$25)*0,05;0)
```

This is how it works:

1. `RANK(A1;$A$1:$A$25;0)` will rank the value inside the list, in **descendent** order.
2. `ROUNDUP(COUNTA($A$1:$A$25)*0,05;0)` will count how many cells are in the list (25) and will get the 5% (multiplying by 0,05, change 0,05 to the % you need), and it will round it up (in this case, the output will be 2).
3. Last Step will compare the value of Step 1 with the value of step 2. If it's less or equal to 2 (in this case), it will be highlighted as you can see

Please, note that this CFR may not work properly if there are blanks values.

Also, the good thing is that changing the 0,05 part to whatever % you need, the CFR will update perfectly. You can even bind it to a cell, and change the value of the cell manually :)

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I can definitely see this formula working on my report. During my tests, I realized that the code I wrote above actually works. I just had a value of 0 for the variable, which is why the macro kept stopping. After correcting the formula and adding an If statement before the vba code, everything worked out.

Answer (score 0):

*AppliesTo* property gives you the range where the condition applies.
You can then get the cell count from that, multiply it with the 5% and round it up using a WorksheetFunction.

```
.Rank = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(.AppliesTo.Cells.Count * 0.05, 0)
.Percent = False
```